# What is the structure-activity relationship of cocaine?

Tags: molecular-structure, drugs, structural-formula, structural-biology

[Cocaine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocaine) is a widely known drug for both recreational and pharmacological uses. What exactly is the relationship of its structure to its drug activity?

Comment: This may be helpful:  https://www.drugabuse.gov/publications/research-reports/cocaine/how-does-cocaine-produce-its-effects

Comment: What you already know about this topic? Without a bit of knowledge about receptors answer may be not all that useful...